# Open the same file with emacs from two user accounts

Tags: emacs

I have two user accounts on my Mac.
I would like to open the same text file on both accounts with emacs.
I can put the file in a directory where both users have read and write access.

When I add text to one process I would like it to show up in the other buffer and vice verse automatically.

I have tried combinations of auto-save-mode and auto-revert-mode to try to auto save an auto revert, but that does not seem to work quite right.

Is there some normal way to do this with emacs?

Comment: Are you implying that you have two users logged in at the same time on one computer (e.g., a server) and you want both users to be able to simultaneously view the same file and have it update in real-time on each station?  Can you please elaborate on how your dual login is set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should learn about collaborative editing. There is a page on the emacs wiki about it [link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CollaborativeEditing)

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer. Just some thoughts. Nevertheless, this is formulated as answer since I want to supplement it with elisp code and maybe refine it later on. This is not possible with comments.

I assume that you are actually working with two emacsen at the two accounts. Furthermore, I assume that the problem with `auto-revert-buffer` is the timing, i.e. that `auto-revert-buffer` works with polling and not on demand.

If you want to update on demand you have to setup both emacsen as servers and give them the possibility to communicate bidirectionally.

You could do something like that via `emacsclient` with the option `-e` over `ssh`.

If you are in a private network you can also let the emacs servers directly communicate.
I had no luck with `emacsclient` and the default server-setup as sockets since `emacsclient` checks the ownership for the sockets. (Note: First, I used emacsclient for testing. Afterwards, I verified that the communication also works between two emacsen.)

But the code below shows a possibility with the emacs server communicating over tcp/ip.

Both emacsen should put their server files into the same directory. Naturally, you need to name the servers differently. Then you can communicate via the command `server-eval-at`.

**Note, this stuff is security relevant and should only be used on a secure private network.**

The below elisp code is not like a package but more like a collection of useful commands.
Nevertheless, on one server you can use the commands as they are. On the other one you need small modifications. E.g.: changing `server-name`.

```lisp
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Communication over tcp:

(setq server-use-tcp t)

(setq server-auth-dir "/tmp/eserv/")

(if (file-directory-p server-auth-dir)
    (progn
      (unless (file-accessible-directory-p server-auth-dir)
    (error "Cannot access server-auth-dir"))
      (unless (file-writable-p  server-auth-dir)
    (error "Cannot write to server-auth-dir"))
      )

  (mkdir server-auth-dir t)

  (unless (shell-command (concat "chgrp users \"" server-auth-dir "\""))
    (error "Cannot change group of server file directory to users."))

  (chmod server-auth-dir (file-modes-symbolic-to-number "g+xr" (file-modes server-auth-dir))))

;; 
(defadvice server-ensure-safe-dir (around unsafe activate)
  "We are on a private network and do not fear intrusion.
Furthermore, the directory is already set up.
This is a SECURITY HOLE if you do not know what you are doing!"
  (let ((dir (ad-get-arg 0)))
  (unless (file-exists-p dir)
    (error "File %s does not exist." dir))
  (unless (file-directory-p dir)
    (error "File %s is not a directory." dir))))

(server-force-delete)
(server-start)

(defvar server-file nil
  "Full name of server file.")
(setq server-file (concat server-auth-dir server-name))

(unless (shell-command (concat "chgrp users \"" server-file "\""))
  (error "Cannot change group of server file to users."))

(chmod server-file (file-modes-symbolic-to-number "g+r" (file-modes server-file)))
```

Afterwards, I discovered that communication of two emacsen is also possible via sockets. One only needs to get around the security and to soft-link the server sockets in the auth-directories.

So, you have the choice.